# Figma: using components from one file in another

Tags: figma, library

I'm an iOS developer trying to learn graphic design, currently using the free version of Figma. I just started and so far it's been lots of fun.

My problem is incorporating iOS system elements into my design, i.e. nav bars, status bars etc. I have no wish designing them myself, so I started looking for existing online designs and found many, some are free, like [this](https://www.figma.com/community/file/809487622678629513). So I choose `duplicate` on the top right corner, and then `move to project`, and it is added to my project as a **separate file**.

The problem is that I cannot use the components within that file in another file, where I have my own design. I assume there's a way to do it or there would be no use for all this online libraries.

Cheers!

Comment: Check the Apple Devoloper site. see https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/ According to [Figma](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041003114-Import-files-into-Figma), it can import Sketch files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you need to ensure the components you want to share are created as "components". Then you need to publish your file as a "library" so that other files can reference it.

Let me know if you need me to expand on certain areas.